# Can we run simple shell script in android system using react native?

Tags: android, react-native

I am writing a simple app using **react native** to make some file operations done automatically. I have tried packages like **strong text** react-native-fs, but I found that there are some files/folders that can not be read using

```
RNFS.ls(PATH).
```

Trying to list files in that folder will throw an exception.

However, these files can be displayed using **ls** command in **adb shell**. So I am wondering if there is a way that we can run shell commands in react native like we make some system calls in java/python?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

### Write your own Native Module.

You can easily run a shell command from Java and call it from React Native using React Native's Native Modules. You can find more information here:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.60/native-modules-android#callbacks

And for your Java command, you'd want to use *something* like this:

```
String command = "ls " + path; // Where path is your desired path.

Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();

Process result = runtime.exec( command );

BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( result.getInputStream() ) );

String[] parts = bufferedReader.readLine().split( "\\s+" );
```

Answer (score 0):

[@flyskywhy/react-native-android-shell](https://github.com/flyskywhy/react-native-android-shell) works well even with root command e.g.

```
AndroidShell.executeCommand('su -c ifconfig eth0 down; su -c ifconfig eth0 hw ether 19:21:19:49:20:21; su -c ifconfig eth0 up', (result) => {
  console.log(result)
});
```